# What does 'it' refer to?

Tags: meaning

What does the word 'it' refer to in the following sentence:`It is dark outside`?

Comment: @Mick Do what thou wilt

Comment: "It" is a dummy subject. It doesn't refer to anything (expect the absence of light). This is a common enough enquiry to be flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mick Verily my son

Comment: Indubitably, Dad. :P

Comment: Now tell me son how shalt i delete my moronic question?

Comment: I don't really know. I've never asked a question here. I do know that you can't do it once someone has posted an answer.

Comment: @Mick that ain't good tho

Comment: An answer. These are comments.

Comment: @Mick but i still see no delete button

Comment: You may have to go into your account page (click on you avatar on the navigation bar). You should then see a list of questions. Click on the question and you should then get a delete link below the question.

Comment: @Mick i see that not.But anyways thanks for thy help.See thou on my next imbecile question

Comment: @Mick Good be with ye

Comment: And with thy spirits. ;-)